# route all traffic through another server without using VPN server?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, routing, iptables

Let's say I have 2 servers

Server A and Server B

I want all traffic from server B to pass through Server A (like a proxy for the whole system), I understand one way to do this is by using a VPN server on Server A. But as far as I know there is a way to do this by using iptables or ip route which will be very reliable.

How can this be achieved? both machines are running Debian Linux.

Each server is hosted at a different ISP

Comment: Another way is to use a proxy hosted on the server you want to route traffic through

Comment: How do you know that method "will be very reliable"?

Comment: @grawity with VPN the client could lose connection and start using the main connection but with iptables or ip route there is no sessions so it seems like a more simple approach

Comment: If i understand what your asking, have you looked into sshuttle?

Comment: If both servers are in different locations and in different networks, you need *some* sort of tunnel. A VPN is one way (and it can be configured to re-connect automatically, so it's not unreliable). Other ways are a GRE or an IPIP tunnel, but these are not encrypted and anyone can MITM, so I'd really prefer a VPN in your place ...

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be achieved unless both computers are in the same subnet.

If they are, then you'd first configure server A as the "default gateway" for B – and similarly the *real* gateway needs the opposite route towards B via A:

- on server B: `to 0.0.0.0/0 via <A's IP>`
- on real gateway: `to <B's IP>/32 via <A's IP>`

But if they're on different networks at all (as you said "hosted at a different ISP"), the *only* way you could use A as the gateway would be to set up a virtual layer-2 network – which is, yes, a VPN.

(This excludes IP "source routing", which has been removed with fire from most modern network stacks due to security issues.)

If you're concerned about privacy (traffic "leaks"), configure server B such that the *only* default route it has is via the VPN – if it only talks with server A, then it only needs a specific "host route" (a /32 or a /128) towards A. For example:

- `to ::/0 via <A's internal IP>`
- `to <A's external IP>/128 via <real default gateway>`

Answer (score -1):

using iptables:

try this:
obviously change the interface according to your setup.

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.3.2